# Why does my SVG image display perfectly on chrome but when I open it on my iPhone it simply does not display?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, vector

Any guidance is much appreciated... this is how i'm doing it.

Is there another easier way I should be displaying an SVG.

Keep in mind all I have at my disposal is a text box that allows HTML...

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1zo2ZJb18abw4ejafQ3LaW5Lv_aZgX6r9" onerror="this.src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=18r53wPextHZJ0iPJQRzhJixMEZsjjtic' alt="You don't have to be great to start, but you have to start to be great" width="100%" height="100%" ">
```

I tried to put in a redundancy png but that didn't work either :(

Comment: Does it work if you remove `export=download` from you url i.e. https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1zo2ZJb18abw4ejafQ3LaW5Lv_aZgX6r9

Comment: Yup thanks so much!! no idea why but that somehow worked :D

Comment: ok I've converted my comment to an answer, please accept it if it's OK for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `export=download` from you url i.e. https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1zo2ZJb18abw4ejafQ3LaW5Lv_aZgX6r9 to prevent a forced download.